# Radius + SSH Key Authentication

Tags: pam, radius, keys

Does anyone know if it is possible to configure pam to require both radius AND ssh-key to successfully authenticate ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSH key check is done by `sshd` itself *before* calling PAM. And while the SSHv2 protocol itself allows multiple authentication methods, most SSH daemons do not support requiring more then one.

However, if you have [OpenSSH 6.2](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.2) or newer, you can use the new `AuthenticationMethods` option to require `publickey` *and* one of `password`|`keyboard-interactive` to succeed:

```
AuthenticationMethods  publickey,password  publickey,keyboard-interactive
```